# Plotting the Digraph with graphviz in python from DOT file

Tags: python-2.7, graph, graphviz, dot

This is the [API reference](http://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) for `graphviz`. I could not find any method that generates a directed graph from an existing `dot` source file. Methods like `render` and `view` save in a new file.

How can I display a graph from existing `dot` code?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I was able to solve it using `Source` class.

```
from graphviz import Source
temp = """
digraph G{
edge [dir=forward]
node [shape=plaintext]

0 [label="0 (None)"]
0 -> 5 [label="root"]
1 [label="1 (Hello)"]
2 [label="2 (how)"]
2 -> 1 [label="advmod"]
3 [label="3 (are)"]
4 [label="4 (you)"]
5 [label="5 (doing)"]
5 -> 3 [label="aux"]
5 -> 2 [label="advmod"]
5 -> 4 [label="nsubj"]
}
"""
s = Source(temp, filename="test.gv", format="png")
s.view()
```

[image: Output]

The output will be in same folder, and format can be altered.

**PS** - To install `graphviz` on Ubuntu. First install using 
`sudo apt install graphviz` and then `sudo pip install graphviz`, else it won't work.

Comment: I get a strange error `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'splitlines'`

Comment: @johnktejik I similarly got `AttributeError: 'Dot' object has no attribute 'splitlines'`. Solved it by running `dot.to_string()` before passing to `Source()`

Answer (score 18):

You can use the `Source.from_file('/path/to/dot_file')` function as defined in the [API](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#graphviz.Source.from_file).

Thus the code will be:

```
from graphviz import Source
path = '/path/to/dot_file'
s = Source.from_file(path)
s.view()
```

Comment: python3.7 /tmp/graphviz.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/graphviz.py", line 3, in <module>
    from graphviz import Source
  File "/tmp/graphviz.py", line 3, in <module>
    from graphviz import Source
ImportError: cannot import name 'Source' from 'graphviz' (/tmp/graphviz.py)

Comment: it flashed on my screen for a millisecond then disappeared.  How do I get it to stay?

Answer (score 0):

I put a very short code for displaying graph using a dot file in Python.

The code is like this:

```py
from graphviz import Source

path = 'abcd.dot'
s = Source.from_file(path)
print(s.source)

s.render('abcd.gv', format='jpg',view=True)
```